# How to check unsupported browsers of application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, user-agent

Is there any way to check unsupported browsers of the application while run the application ?

I need this for ASP.NET MVC4 application.

Means,i want to check whether the user agent(web browser) is supported by the application or not ?

Answer (score 0):

you as the developer should decide which browser is supported by your application, and for that you can use Request.Browser in your controller, there is a lot of useful information